# Should I blur video before compression or during using a filter with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, blur

I have about 3 minutes of video of a street scene. I want the full frame of video blurred so the people, cars, etc. are not recognizable. In addition I want to make the video file size as small as possible for a web site video background. The original footage is 1920x1080, the final size will be 800x450. My question is: Should I blur the video before I compress it with ffmpeg OR should I use ffmpeg to blur the video during compression for best results.

Comment: This is not related to programming, therefore completely off-topic.

Comment: There is no blurring during compression. It will always be needed before compression! The only bad thing to do would be blurring before compression, but using an intermediate lossy-encoder (=losing quality). The correct ways would be: use a frameserver (like avisynth) / use pipes / blur within ffmpeg (if possible; internal piping) / emergency: blur and encode lossless; then call encoder.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter to `ffmpeg` if you use an input that is blurred beforehand or not because it will fully decode the input to raw video:

```
 _______              ______________
|       |            |              |
| input |  demuxer   | encoded data |   decoder
| file  | ---------> | packets      | -----+
|_______|            |______________|      |
                                           v
                                       _________
                                      |         |
                                      | decoded |
                                      | frames  |
                                      |_________|
 ________             ______________       |
|        |           |              |      |
| output | <-------- | encoded data | <----+
| file   |   muxer   | packets      |   encoder
|________|           |______________|
```

<sub>Diagram from [`ffmpeg` Documentation: Detailed description](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Detailed-description).</sub>

If you want to filter then it will do so between *decoded frames* and *encoder*:

```
 _________                        ______________
|         |                      |              |
| decoded |                      | encoded data |
| frames  |\                   _ | packets      |
|_________| \                  /||______________|
             \   __________   /
  simple     _\||          | /  encoder
  filtergraph   | filtered |/
                | frames   |
                |__________|
```

<sub>Diagram from [`ffmpeg` Documentation: Filtering](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Filtering).</sub>

So the easiest method is to simply blur it using one of the many [FFmpeg filters](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) instead of using whatever tool to unnecessarily blur + re-encode before giving it to `ffmpeg`.

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "scale=800:-2,boxblur=8" -preset slow -crf 30 -movflags +faststart -an output.mp4
```